# How to populate angular table with data from RestAPI database?

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

Im trying to populate an angular table with data received from a restapi database but i cannot get it to populate at all.  I can send the data to the console with console.log but i need to populate a table which i am unsure of how to do, any help is appreciated.

partycomponent.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let parties of partyArray">
    <td>{{PARTY.MNEMONIC}}</td>
    <td>{{PARTYNAME}}</td>
    <td>{{PARTYCOLOUR}}</td>
 </tr>
```

parties.component.ts

```
 parties = [];
  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) { 
    httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/parties')
    .subscribe(obj => {
      console.log(obj);
      this.parties = obj as any[];
    })
  }
```

I can put the data into the console from the sql link above but cannot put it on screen inside the table I have made.

My sql works correctly and the link is correct as i can post the data to the console but just cannot seem to get it posting on screen.  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let party of parties">
    <td>{{party.PARTY_MNEMONIC}}</td>
    <td>{{party.PARTYNAME}}</td>
    <td>{{party.PARTYCOLOUR}}</td>
 </tr>
```

You are binding it wrongly.

Comment: Ive made the changes but It is still not populating the table, is the let parties of partyArray correct im new to this language so im unsure

Comment: post here the response you received.

Comment: 0: {PARTY_MNEMONIC: "AON", PARTYNAME: "Aontú", PARTYCOLOUR: "4650b9"}
1: {PARTY_MNEMONIC: "FF", PARTYNAME: "Fianna Fáil", PARTYCOLOUR: "14aa55"}
2: {PARTY_MNEMONIC: "FG", PARTYNAME: "Fine Gael", PARTYCOLOUR: "00a0e1"}
3: {PARTY_MNEMONIC: "GP", PARTYNAME: "Green Party", PARTYCOLOUR: "91b905"}
4: {PARTY_MNEMONIC: "IND", PARTYNAME: "Independent", PARTYCOLOUR: "dc9b14"}
5: {PARTY_MNEMONIC: "LAB", PARTYNAME: "Labour", PARTYCOLOUR: "d7323c"}

Comment: i receive that in the console but its not populating within the table, the sql works but im messing something up to fill the table just

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212298/discussion-between-anonymous-and-patrick-mc).